# Are there any apache configurations to enhance web crawling performance?

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a php web crawler which, when run on localhost, often freezes after a few pages, leaving my web browser to show a loading sign and nothing more.

I have checked through my code, there could be an error with it .. though after looking at it for the last few hours I am ready to explore other possibilities.

When my scraper is running, it dumps information as different processes begin and end. I also frequently flush(); to ensure the browser is showing them ost up to date message. (this gives a console type look to the browser).

The reason I am looking into Apache configuration now is because my program doesn't always freeze in the same place. Sometimes it freezes when it is searching for the 'a' tags for new URLs to add to the queue, other times it freezes when downloading the xhtml data itself, at this point:

```
 private function _getXhtml() {
        $curl = curl_init();
        if (!$curl) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to init curl. ' . curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_urlCurrent);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // Faking user agent
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        $xhtml = curl_exec($curl);
        if (!$xhtml) {
            $xhtml = null;
            echo 'PROBLEM' . $this->_urlCurrent . '<br />';
            //throw new Exception('Unable to read XHTML. ' . curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $xhtml;
    }
```

Besides all of this, I am wondering if there are any amendments to apache's configuration file or PHP.ini that I can do to enhance the localhost environment for web scraping?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I believe I have narrowed it down to Zend_Dom_Query. This is why my application crashes at different stages (sometimes when it's grabbing a href for the crawling list and other times when it's looking for certain things within the page to 'harvest')

Here's an example of my output.

**Here, the application is crashing on the first page.. while getting a url.**

```
    string(25) "Scraping page number 0..." 
string(9) "Mining..." 
string(15) "Getting <a>...." 
string(24) "Finished getting <a>...." 
string(20) "Getting <a href>...." 
string(43) "Mining page http://www.a-site.co.uk/ ..." 
string(17) "New page found..." 
string(18) "Page confirmed...." 
string(29) "Finished Getting <a href>...." 
string(20) "Getting <a href>...." 
string(43) "Mining page http://www.a-site.co.uk/ ..." 
string(29) "Finished Getting <a href>...." 
string(20) "Getting <a href>...."
```

**And here, the application is failing while extracting a  element**

```
string(25) "Scraping page number 5..."
string(9) "Mining..."

//This bit loops for around 70 URLS
string(15) "Getting <a>...."
string(24) "Finished getting <a>...."
string(20) "Getting <a href>...."
string(48) "Mining page http://www.a-site.org ..."
string(29) "Finished Getting <a href>...."
//end loop

string(70) "Harvesting http://www.a.site.org/a-url-path/..."
string(19) "Harvesting html element..."
```

Comment: Oh, I should mention. It never throws an exception. It basically acts like it's not loading. It could be the host that I am scraping, however I have tried multiple websites with the same (or simular) result.

Comment: I wonder if you end up with too many open requests at the same time. Can you / do you write to your "console" the requests as you make them? Could it be that, since you are running on localhost, your crawler ends up trying to index itself - which is going to put you in an infinite loop?

Comment: Can you make it work with just a "simple" website - one that has just simple html and maybe a few pictures? In other words - is this a problem of scale, or logic?

Comment: Are you crawling local sites or remote ones?

Comment: @Floris I am starting to think that I am making too many requests, however, since the script is not multi-threaded, and I know that nothing is being crawled while frozen, I can only assume the infinite loop to be a php error somewhere ... and there isn't one.

Comment: @TimFountain Remote sites. The application constraints to a single host. (So the crawler cannot wonder into other websites)

Answer (score 0):

The script looks fine so it's probably the sites you're crawling
Try adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); //timeout in seconds.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout in seconds.
```

You could also try to make your scraper look more like a real browser. Personally I use my own headers which I can find using fiddler2, then recreate them in curl.